# Keyboard Not detecting input

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am making a website, and am trying to make a keyboard shortcut, but it can't detect the key.

Here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "l" && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("Please Work I Beg Of You");
  }
});
```

Comment: Is that the actual code? It's syntactically invalid as the highlighting shows.

Comment: No I typed it out on my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No more information needed. The computer will read the L key as being capital because you pressed shift, so just change it to "L" (I'm not sure if this'll work, but might also be able to do `e.key.toLowerCase()`). Let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

you can check keyCode instead

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 76 && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) console.log("Please Work I Beg Of You");
});
```